# Space Complexity js functions

Tags: javascript, space-complexity

What is the space complexity and how we can obtain it? (where `a` and `b` are arrays of numbers of size `N` and `M`)

```
a.filter(function(v) {
   return !b.includes(v);
})
```

Comment: Space complexity is the proportion of additional memory your algorithm needs related to the size of the inputs (N and M). What additional memory do `filter` and `includes` need?

Answer (score 9):

Space complexity is a mathematical measure of amount of memory your algorithm/function/program needs to store it's variables. Just like time complexity is measure of how much time your function needs to run.

**TL;DR** You cannot obtain it by any JS function. It is something you have to "calculate". In your algorithm, using two arrays, the space complexity would be `O(n)`.

**Explanation** If you want to know bit more about space complexity: In computer science world the space complexity uses the "big Oh" notation (`O(something)`). And it is something you find out by analyzing your function. Usually by taking a "long hard stare" at your code

For example this function:

```
function add(x,y) { return x+y; }
```

Has space complexity of `O(1)`. Because it uses two variables to store its data: `x` and `y`. So technically you use *two* "places" in your memory space. The question is, since you use **two** places, why the complexity is `O(1)`? Answer to that is, that complexity is expressed in "scale". That means, that if your function needs 1, 2, 3, ... 5 variables to run we  are still talking about "ones" or constants. Therefore `O(1)` or a "constant complexity".

Another example :

```
function sum(arr, n) {
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<n; i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
  }
}
```

In this case the space complexity of this function is `O(N)` Why? Because we are using an array of certain length. This array can have length of 3, but it can also store 100 000 values. Since we are not talking about just "ones" here (or, we cannot be sure that it would be just few values), computer science guys decided that we would denote it as `O(N)` or "linear complexity".

And so on and on. For example, if you would need a 2D array in your program it would probably have `O(N^2)` or "quadratic complexity". In some cases you can bump into  programs with logarithmic and (hopefully not) "exponential" space complexities of `O(log N)` or `2^O(N)`.

Read more about it [here](https://www.cs.northwestern.edu/academics/courses/311/html/space-complexity.html), [here](https://www.studytonight.com/data-structures/space-complexity-of-algorithms) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) (it's about time comlexity, but the measure is the same)